# Find acceleration when v(t) = 0

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am struggling with this...

This was a question I got wrong on a test, and I obviously did not even know how to solve it, so any help is greatly appreciated!

This is a simple velocity/acceleration question

$$s(t)=3\sin(2t-4)$$

**Find v(t)**

$$v(t)=6\cos(2t-4)$$

**Find a(t)**

$$a(t)=-12\sin(2t-4)$$

**Find the acceleration of the particle when v(t)=0**

Now, from what I understand, I need to set the velocity function equal to zero and solve for t, and then take the t value and plug it into my acceleration function... however, I am running into issues and getting very sloppy results. I am assuming I am doing something wrong, or am simply approaching it the wrong way.

$$6\cos(2t-4)=0$$

Where do I begin/How do I solve this?

Even when I consult WolframAlpha, I am getting the following answer for t

$$t=\frac{1}{4}(\pi(3-2n)+8)$$

Comment: *Hint:* When does $\cos\theta = 0$? For $\theta = \pi/2 + k\pi$, $k$ an integer. Now, for those values of $\theta$, what is $\sin\theta$ equal to? $\sin(\pi/2 + k\pi) = (-1)^{k}$, that is $\pm 1$.

Comment: So can I simply set $$2t-4=\pi/2$$ and solve for t?

Comment: giving me $$t=(\pi+8)/4$$

Comment: No, you don't need to solve for $t$ explicitly, it's enough to solve for the argument used in the expressions for velocity and acceleration, namely $2t - 4$. When $v(t) = 0$, we have

$$2t - 4 = \pi/2 + k\pi \ \quad \text{ for some integer } k$$

Now substitute that expression for $2t - 4$ into your equation for acceleration.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, since $$sin(\pi/2+k\pi)=(\pm1)$$ the acceleration is $$-12*\pm1$$ ?

Comment: Yes ... just wrote the answer out below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give the answer with the logic outlined in the comments:

$v(t) = 0$ implies $\cos(2t - 4) = 0$. Thus

$$2t - 4 = \pi/2 + k\pi \quad \text{ for some integer } k$$

In that case

$$a(t) = -12\sin(2t - 4) = -12\sin(\pi/2 + k\pi) = -12\cdot(-1)^k$$

Therefore

$$v(t) = 0 \ \Longrightarrow \ a(t) = \pm 12$$

Comment: Physically, this is an example of an important behavior in simple harmonic motion: the acceleration has maximum magnitude when the velocity is zero. (And conversely, the velocity has maximum magnitude when the acceleration is zero.)

Comment: I appreciate the work through. I wasn't applying reasoning to this and ended up getting stuck as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Let's begin with a fact: $2t-4$ is ugly. There is too much ugliness in the world, so let's instead say that $2t-4 = \theta$. Now this is better, we can instead write our equations as

$$\begin{align*}s(\theta(t)) &= 3\sin \theta(t), \\
v(\theta(t)) &= 3\cos \theta(t) \frac{d\theta}{dt}, \\
a(\theta(t)) &= -3\sin\theta(t)\left(\frac{d\theta}{dt}\right)^2 + 3\cos\theta(t) \frac{d^2 \theta}{dt^2}.
\end{align*}$$

Where'd these $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$ come from? We mustn't forget the chain rule! Fortunately for us, we have a simple case: $\frac{d\theta}{dt} = 2$ and $\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2} = 0$.

This gives us:

$$\begin{align*}s(\theta(t)) &= 3\sin \theta(t), \\
v(\theta(t)) &= 3\cos \theta(t) \cdot 2, \\
a(\theta(t)) &= -3\sin\theta(t)\cdot 2^2 + 3\cos\theta(t) \cdot 0,
\end{align*}$$

which simplifies to

$$\begin{align*}s(\theta(t)) &= 3\sin \theta(t), \\
v(\theta(t)) &= 6\cos \theta(t), \\
a(\theta(t)) &= -12\sin\theta(t).
\end{align*}$$

Ah, now we're talking. This should be much easier. Suppose now that $v(\theta(t)) = 0$. As one knows, $\cos \theta = 0$ when $\theta = \frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2}$. But actually, this is irrelevant!! Why? Because when $\cos \theta = 0$, we have $\sin\theta = \pm 1$.

Therefore, from our relations as derived above, we must have that $a(t) = \pm 12$ whenever $v(t) = 0$.

Comment: I wish I had enough rep to upvote. This is a great answer, but I have to give the checkmark to Simon